# Ruby on rails - find_by_sql with LIKE query issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to define a scope like the following. I have used the "find_by_sql" method for this. I wanted to have the LIKE query with this. But when I construct the query like this I am getting the following error.

```
scope :search_by_id_title, -> (text) do

    WorkOrder.find_by_sql["SELECT work_orders.id, work_orders.line_item_header_id, work_orders.created_by_id, work_orders.created_on, 
............WHERE (line_item_headers.item_location_id = 1) AND (customers.title LIKE, #{text}%)"]
end
```

============== Error ===============

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
```

In the controller I am calling the above scope as the following.

```
@work_orders = WorkOrder.search_by_id_title(params[:search])
```

Can anyone please help to sort out the issue ?

Comment: How do you call the scope?

Comment: I am calling the scope like this.
@work_orders = WorkOrder.search_by_id_title(params[:search])

Comment: Please, post full backtrace of the error in the question

Comment: Yes @Vasilisa done

Comment: Looks like you should change `[]` to `()` for `find_by_sql`

Comment: @Vasilisa is right. I tried your code and it fails because of the `[]`. Also I think you should add a `FROM` clause i.e. `...FROM work_orders as w, line_item_headers as l WHERE ....`

Answer (score 2):

I've not used the find_by_sql, I generally use a where clause, but in that where I would write something like this.

```
WorkOrder.joins(:line_item_header).where('line_item_headers.item_location_id = 1 AND customers.title LIKE ?', "%#{text}%")
```

I'm guessing at your DB setup here. If each work order belongs to a line item header, do the above. If each work order has many line item headers, do the following.

```
WorkOrder.joins(:line_item_headers).where('line_item_headers.item_location_id = 1 AND customers.title LIKE ?', "%#{text}%")
```

The question mark allows you to put the `text` variable outside of the initial query statement. It works with multiple question marks, too. Check out [Active Record Querying](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) section 2.2.